# The authentication or decryption has failed error when making an SSL webservice call using Xamarin and an Android Emulator

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin

I am developing a Xamarin mobile Android app.  For data access, the app uses a Portable class library to make webservice calls to the back end.  I’m using the Portable class library so that I can share it with an iOS version of the mobile app later.  The data is sensitive and requires SSL for all communications which is configured in the WebAPI web service project.  It uses oAuth for authentication.

The challenge I’m running into is that the initial request to authenticate is failing when I run it locally with the following error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request
System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
```

Some additional information:
I am using the following built in Visual Studio emulator and version - Android_Accelerated_x86 (Android 6.0 – API 23).
I am currently running it on localhost and following is the code snippet for this call:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler())
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://10.0.2.2:44342/")  // I also tried installing it on IIS and using port 443 on localhost.  Same problem.
};


var content = new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=[USER_NAME]&password=[PASSWORD]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("Token", content).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var stuffList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stuff>>(data);
    return stuffList;
}
else
{
    return new List<Stuff>();
}
```

The call works when I test it through Fiddler on localhost, so I know that everything is configured correctly on the web service end and with authentication.  But from the emulator my understanding is that I need to use IP address 10.0.2.2.  I have create a self-signed cert and that hasn’t seemed to help.

I have also attempted to use Fiddler as a middleman, but I’m not seeing any activity in Fiddler when I run the app locally.  I have also tried to change the network settings of the emulator, but it doesn’t appear to be having any affect.  The base emulator seems to be fairly limited in these settings, but I also don’t want to pay for a more advanced one at this point in time.  I have seen a number of posts with similar issues, but none of the existing recommendations that I have found are helping.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I have create a self-signed cert": unless you installed this as trusted certificate, it will not be trusted. It is probably the easiest to use http for local testing.

Comment: I had added the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities, but it had no impact.  When you say test local with http, is there a way to test Oauth without ssl or are you suggesting bypassing authentication for local testing?  My webservice requires ssl, following this advice - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api.  Also my service requires a ClaimsIdentity in order to determine who the user is and I would need to spoof this somehow.